# change a categorical variable to a numeric variable in Stata

Tags: stata, weighted-mean

if income in the data was asked as an interval qs,
i.e. individuals allocate themselves within an income interval/category, 
how do I convert it into a numeric variable in order to get the average income of the sample?

Comment: Perhaps ask on Statalist?

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395152/calculate-ex-from-incomplete-data/395160?noredirect=1#comment741301_395160

Comment: This is one of those questions that may be borderline. It could be seen as mainly a programming question, and those are generally off-limits here. In general, if you didn't ask for their exact income, there may also be no way to accomplish what you want. Alternatively, if you want to use the variable as a dependent variable, and you want to know if any statistical methods are appropriate for this, then we could discuss interval regression.